# Generating URL with headers

Tags: http, url, session-cookies

I'm trying to generate a URL that can be shared, without giving full authenticated access to my application.

I'd like to pass my session token in the header when i generate the URL. This link will then be shared with the recipient who will have access based on the parameters of that session token.

Is there anyway to generate a URL in a way that the session token is defined in the header, or is this not possible and have to be done using URL signing?

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

A url and a header are separate components of a HTTP request. Header cannot be in urls.

However, it is possible to add things to URLs that normally appear in headers. For instance, if I have a header `X-FOO: BAR`, I can also add this to the url: `https://example.org/?X-FOO=BAR`. However, this is not some standard HTTP feature; query parameters and headers don't mean the same thing. This means you need to specifically build your application to support some parameters being sent via the URL. Nothing will do this for you automatically.